# how to pass variablees to subshell while command substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable:  pkgname=com.google.android.youtube

And the command is

su -c "stockapp=$(pm path $pkgname | grep base | sed 'sed 's/package://g')"

I have checked the variable is passed inside the double quotes but not to $() How can I pass the variables there there??

Comment: My original command is 

pkgname=com.google.android.youtube

And the command is

su -c "stockapp=$(pm path $pkgname | grep base | sed 'sed 's/package://g')"

I have checked the variable is passed inside the double quotes but not to $()

How can I pass that there??

Comment: All expansions, including the command substitution, are carried out inside the double quotes _before_ the command (`su`) is called. Your variable, `stockapp`, is set within the shell that `su` spawns, and then it is immediately destroyed together with the shell when it terminates.  It is unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.

Maybe you meant:

```
stockapp=$(
  PKG=$pkgname su -c 'pm path "$PKG"' |
    sed  '/base/!d; s/package://g'
)
```

That is, run the login shell of `root` as `root` with `-c` and `pm path "$PKG"` as arguments (assuming the login shell of `root` is Bourne-like) and `PKG=contents-of-pkgname` in its environment, and process its output to remove all the lines that don't contain `base`, and for the other lines, remove all occurrences of `package:`, and assign that output to the `$stockapp` variable in your shell script.